# How to bind(v-model) data when a list with radio buttons in each list in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am fetching data from API. My data looks like -

```
    [
     {
    id:1,
    name:nameOfTheGroup1,
    participants:[
                   {   
                    id:1,
                    name:participant1
                   },
                   {   
                    id:2,
                    name:participant2
                   }
                 ]
     },
     {
    id:2,
    name:nameOfTheGroup2,
    participants:[
                   {   
                    id:3,
                    name:participant1
                   },
                   {   
                    id:4,
                    name:participant2
                   }
                 ]
    }
  ]
```

As you can see its an array of objects. and in each object has nested array of objects. Basically i am trying to fetch all the groups for current user with its participants.

Now i am showing those in the browser using `v-for` like this -

```
  <h3>Please assign an admin to given groups</h3>

  <div v-for="group in groups">
    {{ group.name }}

    <div v-for="participant in group.participants">
      <input type="radio" value="" v-model=""/>
      <label>{{ participant.name }} </label>
   </div>

   </div>
```

Now, my question is how can i bind this data using v-model to get object/array with

group id and assigned user (radio checked ).

This is my best how i could explain))

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried putting "participant" in v-model and "id" in value?

Comment: @Vallo by doing that it gives this error: `You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your model doesn't have any field for the assigned participant. So, you need to add something like that:

```
   id:1,
    name:'nameOfTheGroup1',
    assignedId: '',
    participants:[
                   {   
                    id:1,
                    name:'participant1'
                   },
                   {   
                    id:2,
                    name:'participant2'
                   }
                 ]
     },
     {
    id:2,
    name:'nameOfTheGroup2',
    assignedId: 3,
    participants:[
                   {   
                    id:3,
                    name:'participant1'
                   },
                   {   
                    id:4,
                    name:'participant2'
                   }
                 ]
```

Then you need to provide binding:

```
    <div v-for="participant in group.participants">
      <input type="radio" v-model="group.assignedId" :value="participant.id" :name="group.id"/>
      <label>{{ participant.name }} </label>
   </div>
```

Do not forget to add "name" attribute to the radio.

Working example is here https://jsfiddle.net/7x46mtr1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a property on **participant**.
Something like this

```
v-model=“participant.status”
```

Comment: Actually this answer should work, it did work for me without any trouble when I replicated your problem.

Comment: whats "status"? is that a built in vue prop?